# WMEncoder throws OutOfMemoryException after one iteration

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, encoder, windows-media-encoder

I'm using WMEncoder for screen recording.
At the first time everything is working properly,
but at the second time `Start()` method throws me `OutOfMemoryException`:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was caught
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
```

My code looks like this and it's on .Net4:

```
// Initialize encoder and set recording parameters
mEncoder = new WMEncoder();
SetRecordingParams(); // If it's relevant I can attach this function

// Set the output file.
mEncoder.EnableAutoArchive = true;
mEncoder.AutoIndex = true;
mEncoder.File.LocalFileName = tempRecFile;

// Start the encoding process.
mEncoder.PrepareToEncode(true);
mEncoder.Start();

// If currently recording, stop recording
if (mEncoder != null &&
    mEncoder.RunState != WMENC_ENCODER_STATE.WMENC_ENCODER_STOPPED)
{

    // Stop recording
    mEncoder.Stop();
}

// Releasing Com object
if (mEncoder != null)
{
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mEncoder);
    mEncoder = null;
}
```

Help me!

## UPDATE

```
 private void SetRecordingParams()
        {
            // Create a source group collection object from the WMEncoder object.
            srcGrpColl = mEncoder.SourceGroupCollection;

            // Add a source group named SG1 to the collection.
            // Create a source object for each type of multimedia content
            // in the source group.
            srcGrp = (IWMEncSourceGroup2)srcGrpColl.Add("SG_1");
            srcVideo = (IWMEncVideoSource2)srcGrp.AddSource(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO);
            srcVideo.SetInput("ScreenCap://ScreenCapture1", "", "");

            // Create a profile collection object from the WMEncoder object.
            mEncoder.ProfileCollection.ProfileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            mEncoder.ProfileCollection.Refresh();
            proColl = mEncoder.ProfileCollection;

            // Create a profile object
            IEnumerator profEnum = proColl.GetEnumerator();
            while (profEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                profile = (IWMEncProfile)profEnum.Current;
                if (profile.Name == "Screen Recording")
                {
                    // Load profile
                    newProfile = new WMEncProfile2();
                    newProfile.LoadFromIWMProfile(profile);

                    audience = newProfile.get_Audience(0);

                    audience.set_VideoFPS(0, paramMaps.fpsMapping[fpsKey] * 1000);
                    audience.set_VideoKeyFrameDistance(0, keyFrameInt * 1000);
                    audience.set_VideoWidth(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * paramMaps.imageQualityMapping[qualityRatioKey] / 100);
                    audience.set_VideoHeight(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * paramMaps.imageQualityMapping[qualityRatioKey] / 100);

                    // Set profile language to client machine's locale.
                    // When recording is done this way, it will assume server's locale when extracted from the DB.
                    // This enables us to know which locale should be used for the file merge.
                    // We have found that when profile is set to the same language as user's locale, the recording
                    // has a "flexible" language definition.
                    int langCount = newProfile.get_LanguageCount(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO, 0);
                    // Remove all existing language definitions from profile
                    for (int i = 0; i < langCount; i++)
                    {
                        newProfile.RemoveLanguage(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO, 0, newProfile.get_Language(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO, 0, i));
                    }
                    // Add current locale as profile language.
                    int lcid = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID;
                    newProfile.AddLanguage(WMENC_SOURCE_TYPE.WMENC_VIDEO, 0, lcid);

                    // Specify this profile object as the profile to use in source group.
                    srcGrp.set_Profile(newProfile);
                }
            }
            mEncoder.VideoComplexity = WMENC_VIDEOCOMPLEXITY.WMENC_COMPLEXITY_LEVEL20;
        }
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to check if it is indeed going out of memory? Such as hitting virtual address limit in `Win32` process. As a guess - the encoder might have internal references and does not get destroyed immediately keeping a hold on resources. Performance Monitor should show you this.

Comment: Thanks @RomanR. I ran Performance Monitor and I didn't saw any problems or failures, What can I do?

Comment: Can you please show use the `SetRecordingParams` and other relevant code, so that we can copy it and repro the problem ourselves, ta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMEncoder is no longer supported by Microsoft apparently. I would recommend looking into the Expression Encoder which make screen capture very easy indeed - http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Encoder4_Overview.aspx. And it saves you the hassle of marshalling and dealing with COM.

Comment: But it slow my process since it's output can't be read by Silverlight (or any other player that isn't windows media player) so I need to convert and it takes time

Comment: Never tried it myself but encoder page previously provided explicitely mentions silverlight support.

Comment: I can tell you that there isn't SL support on ee4 screen capture output

Comment: Sorry to hear it is no help to you. I'll give it a quick look tomorrow anyway as I have just wrapped up a project which did screen capture using expression.

Comment: My knowledge of SL is 0, so my ability to test my output for compatibility is not great. This link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(v=vs.95).aspx seems to imply using a VC1 preset in expression would yield usable content. I have a tiny test file (256K) I could provide for testing.